# Split one row into multiple rows in excel

Tags: excel, formatting

I have an Excel worksheet laid out as follows:

```
Drink     Apple Juice, Orange Juice, Coffee
Cup       Ceramic Cup, Paper Cup, Plastic Cup, Stainless Steel Cup
```

I want to split and collate the cell values to:

```
Drink     Apple Juice
Drink     Orange Juice
Drink     Coffee
Cup       Ceramic Cup
Cup       Paper Cup
Cup       Plastic Cup
Cup       Stainless Steel Cup
```

thanks a lot.

**EDITTED**

Comment: have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this as well:

```
'for getting used range in rows
Function rngused(RowNo As Long) As Range
Dim rngg As Range, lastcol As Range

Set rngg = ActiveSheet.Rows(RowNo)
Set lastcol = rngg.Find(What:="*", After:=Cells(RowNo, 1), SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
Set rngused = Range(Cells(RowNo, 1), Cells(RowNo, lastcol.Column))

Set rngg = Nothing: Set lastcol = Nothing
End Function

'for splitting and merging
Sub SplitCol2Row(rngPassed As Range, offcet As Long)
Dim i As Long, rngMerged As Range

    For i = 2 To rngPassed.Columns.Count
    Set rngMerged = Application.Union(rngPassed(1), rngPassed(i))
    rngMerged.Copy
    Range("A" & i - 1).Offset(offcet, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    Next

Set rngMerged = Nothing
End Sub

'main procedure
Sub Main()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim rngRow As Range, lastrow As Range, ii As Long

    For ii = 2 To 4 'these are source rows
    Set rngRow = rngused(ii)
    Set lastrow = Range("A:A").Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
    SplitCol2Row rngRow, lastrow.Row

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Set rngRow = Nothing: Set lastrow = Nothing
    Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This macro should do it just fine:

```
Sub SplitCellsAndExtend_New()
'takes cells with inside line feeds and creates new row for each.
'reverses merge into top cell.

'turn off updates to speed up code execution
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With


Dim strCell As String, lastRow As Long, lRowLoop As Long, j As Long, arSplit
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Const lColSplit As Long = 2 'update column number for the column that must be split
Const sFirstCell As String = "A1"
Dim sSplitOn As String
sSplitOn = "," 'separating character

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, lColSplit).End(xlUp).Row

    For lRowLoop = lastRow To 1 Step -1

        arSplit = Split(Cells(lRowLoop, lColSplit), sSplitOn)

        If UBound(arSplit) > 0 Then
            Rows(lRowLoop + 1).Resize(UBound(arSplit) + 1).Insert

            Cells(lRowLoop, lColSplit).Resize(, UBound(arSplit) + 1).Value = arSplit
            Cells(lRowLoop, lColSplit).Resize(, UBound(arSplit) + 1).Copy
            Cells(lRowLoop + 1, lColSplit).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True

            Cells(lRowLoop, 1).Resize(, lColSplit - 1).Copy Cells(lRowLoop + 1, 1).Resize(UBound(arSplit) + 1)

            Rows(lRowLoop).Delete
        End If

        Set arSplit = Nothing
    Next


With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End With


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey you could use below one- definitely will going to work

```
      Sub splitbyRow()
      Dim R as Range, I as Long, at
      Set R =worksheet ("sheetName").Range("column- 
        A/B/C99999").End(xlUp)

      Do while R.Row>1
           ar = Split(R.Value, ",") # "," delimiter- change 
                                                      whichever you prefer

           IfUBound(ar) >=0 then R.value =at(0)
          For i = UBound(ar) To 1 Step -1
                R.EntireRow.Copy
                R.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
                R.Offset(1).Value=ar(i)
         Next
              Set R= R.Offset(-1)
        Loop
      End sub
```

If you want multiple delimiter copy from "ar=split....." till "Next", paste it above "Set R....." And change the delimiter you need